# Same height title in bootstrap columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have html (bootstrap css) like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col">   
      <div class="block">    
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
       </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col">   
      <div class="block">
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title <br>more than 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And css like this

```
.block{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.title{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

Title comes as dynamic text so it can be 1, 2, or 3 lines. Is there a way to make `title` height the same height as the height in the 'highest' title with `css only`. I want properties be aligned regardless of the title text coming in from api. I would like the above example to work without setting `min-height: 40px;` because I don't know what min-height should be.

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28125/

Comment: In case you can use jQuery: https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height, another solution can be to adjust the `block` on a specific height.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware this is impossible in css only since the two elements are not siblings of each other. If that was the case `display: table-cell` could have been an option.

However there is a solution for this when using `jQuery` you can look up the highest `.title` element and set all the other `.title` elements to this heights.

See the following snippet:

```
var largest = 0;
//loop through all title elements
$(document).find(".title").each(function(){
  var findHeight = $(this).height();
  if(findHeight > largest){
    largest = findHeight;
  }  
});

$(document).find(".title").css({"height":largest+"px"});
```

See the fiddle for an example: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/28131/

Comment: There is a little mistake in the solution because it will always use the variable "largest" at the end. Please see my approach below.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the table.For solving this problem

```css
.block{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
td.block-cell {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.block-wrap {
  background-color: transparent;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 10px;
}
.title{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><head>
<title>Test</title><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=0'>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <table class="block-wrap">
  <tr>
    <td class="block-cell">   
      <div class="block">    
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
       </div> 
    </td>
 
    <td class="block-cell" >   
      <div class="block">
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title <br>more than 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
       </div>
    </td>
 </tr>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can override the CSS bootstrap, and to make the columns were of the same height using `flexbox`.

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.same-height-wrapp {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.same-height-wrapp > [class*='col-'] {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.block{
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.title{
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.desc-wrapp{
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 15px;
   
 }
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row same-height-wrapp">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col same-height">   
          <div class="block">
            <div class="title">
              <strong>Dynamic title 1 line</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="desc-wrapp">
              <div>
                <i>Prop 1</i>
              </div>
              <div>
                Value 1
              </div> 
            </div>
           </div> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col same-height">   
          <div class="block">
            <div class="title">
            <strong>Dynamic title <br>more than 1 line<br> line 2</strong>
            </div>
            <div class="desc-wrapp">
              <div>
                <i>Prop 1</i>
              </div>
              <div>
                Value 1
              </div>
            </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it want prop1 be at the same level in both blocks

Comment: @jonasnas check this now, its work, but assuming that Prop1 and Value1  always will be have one line, if will be more that code needs to be costomize

Answer (score 1):

With current `HTML` you can't make height of both blocks same with css.

However you can create a fake effect of having same height with `:before` or `:after` pseudo elements.

The trick is to use `position: relative` on `.container` and remove it from child `.col-xs-*` classes. Then use `:before` or `:after` pseudo element with wisely calculated `left` and `width` values.

```
.same-height-container {
  position: relative;
}
.same-height-container .col {
  position: static;
}
.same-height-container .col:before {
  width: calc(50% - 30px - 20px); /* .container left-right padding +
                                     .block left-right margin */
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 25px;  /* container left padding + block left margin */
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
.same-height-container .col + .col:before {
  right: 25px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
  margin: 10px;
}

.block {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.title{
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  min-height: 40px;
}

.same-height-container {
  position: relative;
}

.same-height-container .col {
  position: static;
}

.same-height-container .col:before {
  width: calc(50% - 50px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.same-height-container .col + .col:before {
  right: 25px;
  left: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container same-height-container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col">   
      <div class="block">    
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col">   
      <div class="block">
        <div class="title">
          <strong>Dynamic title <br>more than 1 line Dynamic title <br>more than 1 lineDynamic title <br>more than 1 lineDynamic title <br>more than 1 line</strong>
        </div>
        <div>
          <i>Prop 1</i>
        </div>
        <div>
          Value 1
        </div>  
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I adjust the solution a little bit:

```
function sameheight(div){
    /* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */

    var largest = 160;
    var findHeight = 0;

   //loop through all title elements
    $(document).find(div).each(function(){
      findHeight = $(this).height();
      if(findHeight > largest){
        largest = findHeight;
      }  
});

    $(document).find(div).css({"height":findHeight+"px"});
};
```

Then you can use the function with

```
sameheight(".blogtitle");
```