# Set title element min-height in adjacent columns to be as tall as the tallest title

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so that the content of columns below titles of varying heights all start at the same position in vanilla javascript. The current script is able to set the `min-height` of the titles so that no title is shorter than another. However, once `min-height` has been set the titles cannot become smaller again, even if the size of the column is increased which would allow title in the middle no longer be wrapped.

```js
window.onload = function() {
    sameHeight();
}

window.onresize = function (event) {
    sameHeight();
};

function sameHeight() {
    let matches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-sameheight]');
    let minHeights = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
      let heightGroup = matches[i].getAttribute('data-sameheight');
      if (!minHeights.hasOwnProperty(heightGroup)) {
        minHeights[heightGroup] = matches[i].scrollHeight;
      } else {
        if (minHeights[heightGroup] < matches[i].scrollHeight) minHeights[heightGroup] = matches[i].scrollHeight;
      }
    }

    for (let key in minHeights) {
      let matches = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-sameheight="${key}"]`);
      for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) matches[i].style.minHeight = minHeights[key] + 'px';
    }
}
```

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <h1 data-sameheight="title">title</h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h1 data-sameheight="title">a much longer title</h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>

<div class="col">
  <h1 data-sameheight="title">title</h1>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

How can I fix my script so that at any size the titles are only as tall as the tallest title?

Answer (score 0):

I edited the answer to solve your issue without Javascript. You can utilize flexbox for equal height columns/elements.

Let me know if that helped.

```css
.col {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  width: 25%;
}

.col h1 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="col d-flex flex-column order-1">
    <h1 data-sameheight="title">title</h1>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col d-flex flex-column order-1">
    <h1 data-sameheight="title">long title fsdscd sdcscds</h1>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>

  <div class="col d-flex flex-column order-1">
    <h1 data-sameheight="title">title</h1>
    <p>content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue is not that the column width in the snippet is fixed, it was only set like that as an example to force the longer title to be wrapped. I have updated the snippet to use percent's instead. The problem is once the title has become wrapped and `min-height` has been increased even if you make the screen wider again so the title isn't wrapped the `min-height` will not be set to anything lower than the maximum title height.

Comment: I see the problem now. Let me edit with a much more simple solution without the need for Javascript.

Comment: I don't think this will work since I am using bootstrap in my project. My question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265535/same-height-title-in-bootstrap-columns except I am not using jQuery.

Comment: @Nostupidquestions That shouldn't be a problem. I edited my question to do the exact same thing with bootstrap classes.

Comment: In this example is it possible for the columns to wrap, say if the breakpoint is <xs the columns would take up the entire row?

Comment: Check this https://codepen.io/vmank/pen/KKzYWQj . All you need to do is to change the class on the wrapping div for example I've set it to `d-xl-flex` instead of `d-flex` and now it wraps when the viewport-width is smaller than `xl` as specified in bootstrap.